# How to find the process with maximum file descriptors?

Tags: shell-script

What is wrong with this `for` loop? I am trying to find which process has the maximum number of file descriptors. The first command in the `for` loop `ps aux | awk '{print $2}'` prints out only the process IDs. I know the first error `lsof: illegal process ID: PID` is there because the 1st line of the output is `PID`, but shouldn't the loop work fine for the rest of the lines?

```
[root@serv5 ~]# for i in `ps aux | awk '{print $2}'` ; do `lsof -p $i | wc -l` ; done
lsof: illegal process ID: PID
lsof 4.82
 latest revision: ftp://lsof.itap.purdue.edu/pub/tools/unix/lsof/
 latest FAQ: ftp://lsof.itap.purdue.edu/pub/tools/unix/lsof/FAQ
 latest man page: ftp://lsof.itap.purdue.edu/pub/tools/unix/lsof/lsof_man
 usage: [-?abhlnNoOPRtUvVX] [+|-c c] [+|-d s] [+D D] [+|-f[gG]] [+|-e s]
 [-F [f]] [-g [s]] [-i [i]] [+|-L [l]] [+m [m]] [+|-M] [-o [o]] [-p s]
[+|-r [t]] [-s [p:s]] [-S [t]] [-T [t]] [-u s] [+|-w] [-x [fl]] [--] [names]
Use the ``-h'' option to get more help information.
-bash: 0: command not found
-bash: 22: command not found
-bash: 4: command not found
-bash: 4: command not found
-bash: 4: command not found
-bash: 4: command not found
^C
[root@serv5 ~]#
```

Why is it executing the output of `wc -l` instead of going back to the loop?

Or is there another way I can find the process with maximum file descriptors?

Comment: Well you can fix your command by e.g:  `for i in $(ps aux | awk 'NR>1{print $2}') ; do lsof -p "$i" | wc -l ; done`  and work from here.

Comment: Check the output of `ps aux | awk '{print $2}' | head` and you will notice.

Comment: Since you're already using `lsof`, I suggest parsing the output of `lsof -Fpcn` instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is the backticks in your `do ... done` section.

When writing shell script, you do not need to encapsulate blocks (`if; then ... fi`, `while; do ... done`, etc) in backticks. Doing so results in the shell evaluating the contents of the backticks, and then executing that content. So the backticks are returning a number (the number of open files), and then trying to run that number, resulting in a `command not found`.

Thus you want:

```
for i in `ps aux | awk '{print $2}'` ; do lsof -p $i | wc -l ; done
```

Comment: Thanks. It working, but I have to make a few more changes to get the PIDs listed against those numbers. I can do that. Your answer helped me with what was fundamentally wrong. On an another note, I use this a lot:
"for i in `cat list.txt` ; do `touch $i` ; done" and it works without any errors. I am guessing that it is working fine even with the backticks, since the command in the 'do..' section is not producting any outputs.

Answer (score 3):

This is many year old question but what OP is asking should be possible by using

```
lsof | awk '{print $2}'| uniq -c| sort -n
```

This prints number of files open per pid.

Answer (score 2):

(Your loop has uneeded ``` `` ``` causing the problem via command substitution, as noted by val0x00ff and Patrick. This is for the second part about finding another way to solve the problem.)

You can show the number of file-descriptors per process using `lsof` directly:

```
lsof -Fpcn | nawk '
 /^p/ { pid=substr($0,2) }
 /^c/ { cmd=substr($0,2) }
 /^n/ { fd[cmd"["pid"]"]++ }
 END  { for (cc in fd) printf("%-20s %i\n",cc,fd[cc]) } ' | sort -n -k 2
```

This should work on most *nix systems with `lsof`.

The `-Fpcn` option outputs a "machine readable" format which tags each line:

- PIDs with a leading "p"
- command (name) output with a leading "c"
- file-descriptor output with a leading "n"

The awk script keeps track of the file descriptor count using an associative array (indexed by "command[pid]"), and dumps the array at the `END{}` of input.

These FD counts will often differ from other methods, notable `ps` or `/proc/PID/fd` counts because `lsof` counts more than just real file descriptors, memory mapped files in particular will likely throw your numbers off for some processes.

If you want an accurate count of actual FDs you need to add "-d0-999999" to limit the `lsof` output to just numeric file descriptors. Technically the high number should be at least the maximum number of FDs per process, can probably determine this with `ulimit -n` or `getconf OPEN_MAX` but root can change this. On Linux you can inspect each process's limits in `/proc/PID/limits`, and you can use `/proc/sys/fs/file-nr` as an upper limit.

Other cheap and cheerful ways of counting file descriptors on a Linux system with `/proc`:

```
(cd /proc; ls -d [0-9]* ) | while read pid; do set -- /proc/$pid/fd/*; echo $pid $#; done
ps axo "pid" | while [...]
```

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh` on Linux, you could just do:

```
(){ pid=$1:t; } /proc/<->(nOe['(){ REPLY=$#; } $REPLY/fd/*(N)'])
```

to get into `$pid`, the pid of the process that have the most open file descriptors.

A more verbose version could be:

```
by_number_of_fds() {
  local process_dir=${1-$REPLY}
  local -a fds=( $process_dir/fd/*(N) )
  REPLY=$#fds
}
process_dirs_sorted_by_number_of_fds=(
  /proc/<->(O+by_number_of_fds)
)
pid_with_most_fds=$process_dirs_sorted_by_number_of_fds[1]:t
```