# process with maximum file descriptors - elaborate on the process details

Tags: awk

I am trying to find the process with maximum file descriptors
I found this solution [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163351/how-to-find-the-process-with-maximum-file-descriptors)

```
lsof -Fpcn | awk '
 /^p/ { pid=substr($0,2) }
 /^c/ { cmd=substr($0,2) }
 /^n/ { fd[cmd"["pid"]"]++ }
 END  { for (cc in fd) printf("%-20s %i\n",cc,fd[cc]) } ' | sort -n -k 2
```

This set of commands is running fine,
I was able to filter out processes that has less then 15 descriptors,
I am trying to elaborate on the process details,
So I would like to pull the information about the process from ps for example:

```
  ps -ef  | grep 30394
```

I was able to do the filtering like that:

```
 END  {
           for (cc in fd) {
                 if(fd[cc] > 15){
                         printf("%-20s %i\n",cc,fd[cc])
                         }
                 }

      } ' | sort -n -k 2
```

But i am not sure how to fetch the process information.

When i am trying to incorporate ps -ef like that:

```
 printf("%-20s %i    process details: %s  \n",cc,fd[cc] , "$(ps -ef | grep fd[cc])" ) ;
```

It just prints out:

```
lsof[7626]           17    process details: $(ps -ef | grep fd[cc])
```

Comment: This is not answering your Q, but if on linux you can try `perl -e 'for(</proc/[0-9]*>){ next if $_ eq "/proc/$$"; $p = $_, $m = $n if ($n =()= <$_/fd/*>) > $m }; print join " ", "$m fds:", $p=~/\d+/g, qx(cat "$p/comm")'`.

Comment: what is this output?   4 fds: 25981 bash

Comment: The number of fds, the pid and the process name. Of course, you'll have to run it as root in order to have access to all processes. Here is the actual version which I intended to copy-paste, which segues into `ps`: `perl -e 'for(</proc/[0-9]*>){ next if $_ eq "/proc/$$"; $p = $_, $m = $n if ($n =()= <$_/fd/*>) > $m }; print "== $m fds ==\n"; exec "ps", $p=~/\d+/g'`.

Comment: this is good but lacking process information , after running it you have to pull data from PS, and there are many processes.

Comment: OK, I see that you don't trust to run it, I'm not going to beg you to do it ;-) But what you seem to miss is that __a)__ you can pass PIDs as arguments to `ps` (`ps -f PID` instead of `ps -fe | grep PID`) __b)__ you can adjust what process info `ps` prints: `ps -o pid,uid,args PID`. Both `lsof` and `ps` get their info from dirs and files in `/proc`, so you can bypass both and read it directly; that perl scriptlet simply counts how many entries are in each `/proc/PID/fd`; that's something that unfortunately you cannot do in awk, which doesn't know how to read dirs.

Comment: I trust this, but its really hard for me to parse this perl code ....
Also i dont understand why is it returning only one result (executed as root)    

== 634 fds ==   #
PID  TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND  #
13011 ?        Sl    20:19 /opt/java/bin/java  #

Comment: Isn't that the process with the most fds open? it's easy to adapt the scriptlet to print only processes with >15 fds open, if that's what you want. Eg: `perl -e 'for(</proc/[0-9]*>){ next if $_ eq "/proc/$$"; push @l, /\d+/g if ($n =()= <$_/fd/*>) > 15 }; exec "ps", @l'`. Combining the info returned by `ps` with the nr. of fds open for each process can't be done that nicely (it would be better to read `/proc/PID/stat{,us}` directly from the perl script.